# How do Inherit from custom React Component without losing flow type information?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a BaseComponent which inherits from `React.Component`. All other components in the app inherit from `BaseComponent`. I need to type `BaseComponent` such that other components inheriting from it are handled as React components by Flow. This is what I currently have:

```
class BaseComponent<P, S> extends React.Component<$Shape<P>, P, S> {
  ...
}

class OtherComponent extends BaseComponent {
  props: {};
  state: {}:
  ...
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCWBbADrATgF1AEoCmAhgMa4A0oA3gMKyawB2RzuAvqJNo6AOTZSFfgG5kZaCQDO00ACEZRBk1bsAPAAVqAZQB8oIgA9cbACZyVWNbnUASHQAsSGIlr3VtofbUShQZIzWbLhOsACu0GYAqhhmJKYAFKwmmrwY0gBcoF4pobgJRNk6AJS+-v4goHTh0rh80o4RUaDhcYWgcADmKGSgjkRCAHR+oByI44i4AJ6uOenSACqzRKAAvL4AkEbZzOFoAEaDlKOb07v7R9gT4lMr3gWmy3MbNKOBcNjZ-F1CbPygAA+AiEZgBwP4B2g4SIYhuEiksmqsBwZkMJnMckU0mUQRYIVAWgWzyIukeRBJBje-kCzDq2HCFBwiQwC2yaVgGRJZWpFWkbUGLIWJXEFVAuEcKGkQzqHVeozFHxw31+RH+CrGorGyH8zmYZmgymgvQA1okeRqJVKZUR8oVErzFbBPtkrdLWZzpUZqFUAJLMABuJGNZgAhKAAGJweABHBCCjQaagRoIOSDXjYEZijgi0aTfxCfWCi1ioS4cLYZigRLqMwoAOgFh0Y1kE1rGhuoZ6g1G00cYB6XP+cbjfyIBiooZmIiQEiRXAcjLrcqgHagACMJ385wE6-4PrA-qDIfDUYQsew8dwieTTXgacvOBGHHEQA). 
Flow correctly checks props, state, etc. in `OtherComponent`.

In BaseComponent, however, I get obscure errors:

1. `S:  This type is incompatible with 'undefined. Did you forget to declare S?`
2. `P:  This type is incompatible with 'undefined. Did you forget to declare P?`
3. `Did you forget to declare some incompatible instantiation of`S`?:  This type is incompatible with 'some incompatible instantiation of`S`'`

I'm struggling to understand the errors message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You parameterized `BaseComponent` with `P` and `S`. You need to provide values for that when you extend `BaseComponent`. See https://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html#polymorphic-classes .

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! I am passing the type values through. I've added a flowtype.org/try example demonstrating the issue. Just to clarify, what I'm doing causes flow to correctly type `OtherComponent`, but shows errors for `BaseComponent`. See the working example.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
class BaseComponent<D, P, S> extends React.Component<D, P, S> {
    static defaultProps: D
    props: P
    state: S
    yourCustomFunction(): void
}

class You extends BaseComponent<any, any, any> {
  --- component body ---
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. Re-iterating props/state/defaultProps in `BaseComponent` does solve the issue. The `<any, any, any` on class `You` keeps flow from type-checking, however. I'll a working example.

Answer (score 0):

After a large amount of experimentation, this what I ended up with. It appears to work correctly:

```
class BaseComponent<Props:Object, State, DefaultProps: $Shape<Props>> extends React.Component<DefaultProps, Props, State> {
  static defaultProps: $Abstract<DefaultProps>;
  props: Props;
  state: $Abstract<State>;
}
```

The key was to define props/state/and defaultProps on `baseComponent` in addition to passing the type params through to `React.Components`. I'm not sure why this is necessary, but it does solve the issue.

Comment: You should include the relevant code directly in your answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to have my code work with a variable number of generic arguments, this is how I ended up typing the component:

```
export default class NewComponent<P, S = {}> extends Component<P, S> {
  props: P
  state: S
  ...
}
```